How to Create a Month Over Month KPI that Adapts to User's Date Filter in Amazon QuickSight?
I'm trying to create a KPI that shows Month Over Month (MoM) performance and adapts to the month my user is filtering in QS. My approach is to apply the date filter to everything except this KPI.
Here is what I have tried so far:
1 Calculated Field to Get Maximum Date:
maxIf({data_ref}, {data_ref} >= addDateTime(0, 'YYYY', truncDate('MM', now())) AND  {data_ref} <= addDateTime(0, 'DD', addDateTime(-3, 'HH', now())) )
2 Using the Maximum Date in Another Calculated Field:
countIf({num_pedi_mrke}, truncDate("MM", {data_ref}) = truncDate("MM", {Max_date})) /  countIf({num_pedi_mrke}, truncDate("MM", {data_ref}) = truncDate("MM", addDateTime(-1, 'MM', {Max_date})))
However, I received the following error:

Nested aggregate functions like {{aggregateFunction1}} and {{aggregateFunction2}} are not allowed.

How can I create a Month Over Month KPI that adapts to the month my user is filtering without running into the nested aggregate functions error? Is there a different approach or workaround I should consider?
Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!
